# Does cfldap allow cfqueryparam?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfqueryparam

I want to prevent SQL injection attacks. We have a form that asks for the user's AD username and password. Then our processing code looks something like this:

```
<cfldap name="ldap_result" action="query" server="999.999.999.999" 
attributes="userprincipalname,title,samaccountname,sn,name,mail,cn" 
filter="(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=#form.username#))"
start="dc=us,dc=company,dc=lan"
scope="subtree"
username="US\#form.username#" 
password="#form.password#">
```

I would never run a query with user input without cfqueryparam (to wrap the username and password inputs), but is something like that even available to cfldap?  (We're on CF10 if that makes a difference.)

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, when I tried this, I got the following error:

> Attribute validation error for tag CFLDAP.It does not allow the
>   attribute(s) CFSQLTYPE,VALUE.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  My guess would be a compile error with words to the effect of using a queryparam tag outside a cfquery block.

Comment: I get this:
Attribute validation error for tag CFLDAP.It does not allow the attribute(s) CFSQLTYPE,VALUE.

Comment: Is the answer that it's not necessary since the form variables are being passed to a cf tag rather than directly into a SQL query?  Can we rely on the tag doing the necessary escaping on the input when querying AD?

Comment: I second @DanBracuk's comment. Wouldn't it've been easy to simply *try this* rather than take the time to post a question on S/O, and ask other ppl to sink their time into it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Adam. I did try it, and it failed. But, I didn't point that out in my original post. I'll make an update for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use the `cfqueryparam` tag within your `cfldap` tag. The `cfqueryparam` is used specifically for SQL queries. You are thinking correctly though. **NEVER TRUST USER INPUT**

The `cfldap` tag does give you some protection in and of itself.

> **LDAP injection**
>
> ColdFusion uses the `<cfldap>` tag to communicate with LDAP servers. This tag has an ACTION attribute that dictates the query performed against the LDAP. The valid values for this attribute are: add, delete, query (default), modify, and modifyDN. All `<cfldap>` calls are turned into JNDI (Java Naming And Directory Interface) lookups. However, because `<cfldap>` wraps the calls, it will throw syntax errors if native JNDI code is passed to its attributes, making LDAP injection more difficult.

From page 14 of the [ColdFusion 8 developer security guidelines](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/coldfusion/pdfs/coldfusion_security_cf8.pdf) which you should read if you have not done so already. It was written for ColdFusion 8 but much if not all of it is still relevant. There is an [updated version of the document for ColdFusion 11](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/cfml-developer-security-guide.pdf) but it actually references the version 8 document as a reference as well.

I would suggest that you go with a whitelist approach here. Your active directory has specific requirements for the username and password fields; only lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, etc. Create a regular expression that checks the user input for those valid characters only. If either field contains anything else then deny the submission and do not run the `cfldap` call.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  I was actually thinking I might go the route of a REReplace.  It's a little bit of a pain as I don't make the rules on password requirements/restrictions so I'll need to track those rules down and rely on someone else to maintain them.  But, it's better IMO than a free-for-all.

Comment: Agreed. There will be some maintenance with this approach (if/when the rules change) but definitely don't want to allow just anything.

Comment: OWASP also provides for a reference implementation of encodeForLDAp(): https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.html#encodeForLDAP(java.lang.String). If one is using untrusted values, one should also look to *actively* encode them correctly